# Forward Propagate RNN using Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to create an RNN forward pass method that can take a variable input, hidden, and output size and create the rnn cells needed. To me, it seems like I am passing the correct variables to self.rnn_cell -- the input values of x and the previous hidden layer. However, the error I receive is included below.

I have also tried using x[i] and x[:,i,i] (as suggested by my professor) to no avail. I am confused and just looking for guidance as to whether or not I am doing the right thing here. My prof suggested that since I keep receiving errors, I should restart the kernel in jupyter notebook and rerun code. I have, and I receive the same errors...

Please let me know if you need additional context.

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size

        self.rnn_cell = nn.RNNCell(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        """
        x: size [seq_length, 1, input_size]
        """
        h = torch.zeros(x.size(1), self.hidden_size)

        for i in range(x.size(0)):
            ### START YOUR CODE ###
            h = self.rnn_cell(x[:,:,i], h)
            ### END YOUR CODE ###

        ### START YOUR CODE ###
        # Hint: first call fc, then call softmax
        out = self.softmax(self.fc(self.hidden_size, h.size(0)))
        ### END YOUR CODE ###

        return out 
IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert at RNNs but giving it a try.

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
    super(RNN, self).__init__()
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size

    self.rnn_cell = nn.RNN(input_size, hidden_size)
    self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)


def forward(self, x):
    """
    x: size [seq_length, 1, input_size]
    """
    h = torch.zeros(num_layers(hidden), x.size(0), self.hidden_size)


        ### START YOUR CODE ###
    out,hidden = self.rnn_cell(x, h)
        ### END YOUR CODE ###

    ### START YOUR CODE ###
    # Hint: first call fc, then call softmax
    out = out.contiguous().view(-1, self.hidden_dim) #You need to reshape the output to fit the FC layer
    out = self.fc(out)
    return F.softmax(out)
    ### END YOUR CODE ###

    return out
```

Please try running this and let me know in case of errors or any doubts. (Cannot ask you details as I can't comment rn.)

If you got any idea from my answer, do support.

Answer (score 0):

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size

        self.rnn_cell = nn.RNNCell(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        """
        x: size [seq_length, 1, input_size]
        """
        h = torch.zeros(x.size(1), self.hidden_size)

        for i in range(x.size(0)):
            ### START YOUR CODE ###
            h = self.rnn_cell(x[i,:,:], h)
            ### END YOUR CODE ###

        ### START YOUR CODE ###
        # Hint: first call fc, then call softmax
        out = self.fc(h)
        out = self.softmax(out)
        ### END YOUR CODE ###

        return out
```

Comment: Please add more to the answer that explains why the OP should use your code and how it solves their issue. As it is now it is not really obvious what changes you made.

Answer (score 0):

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size

        self.rnn_cell = nn.RNNCell(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        """
        x: size [seq_length, 1, input_size]
        """
        h = torch.zeros(x.size(1), self.hidden_size)

        for i in range(x.size(0)):
            ### START YOUR CODE ###
            h = self.rnn_cell(x[i,:,:], h)
            ### END YOUR CODE ###

        ### START YOUR CODE ###
        # Hint: first call fc, then call softmax
        out = self.softmax(self.fc(h))
        ### END YOUR CODE ###

        return out
```

Comment: Please add more to the answer that explains why the OP should use your code and how it solves their issue. As it is now it is not really obvious what changes you made. Further it seems that your proposed solution is basically identical with the answer made by Dev Taylor.